# How use global variable in android service

Tags: android, android-service

I have an Android service running in the background.
I monitor the main application every 5 seconds, if it is closed I restart it. After 3 relaunch I would like to display a logs. But the counters are reset to 0 each time, what to do?

```
class MonitoringService: Service() {

    companion object {
        var cmp = 0
    }

    private inner class ServiceHandler(looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.e("TEST SERVICE", "Create Service")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.e("TEST SERVICE", "Start Service")
        val c = this
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            while (true){
                isAppRunning(c, "ch.test.test.mainApp")
                delay(5000)
            }
        }
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.e("TEST SERVICE", "Destroy Service")
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    fun isAppRunning(context: Context, packageName: String): Boolean {
        val activityManager = context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val procInfos = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
        if (procInfos != null) {
            for (processInfo in procInfos) {
                if (processInfo.processName == packageName) {
                    ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(processInfo)
                    if (processInfo.importance != ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
                        val app = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                        cmp =+ 1
                        Log.e("TEST SERVICE",cmp.toString())
                        startActivity(app)
                    }
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate object file with any name and declare a variable inside to capture your counts. like below

```
object Constants {
 var serviceCount = 0
```

}

and use this variable in service like Constants.serviceCount instead of cmp

```
class MonitoringService: Service() {

private inner class ServiceHandler(looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {
}

override fun onCreate() {
    Log.e("TEST SERVICE", "Create Service")
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.e("TEST SERVICE", "Start Service")
    val c = this
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        while (true){
            isAppRunning(c, "ch.test.test.mainApp")
            delay(5000)
        }
    }
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    Log.e("TEST SERVICE", "Destroy Service")
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

fun isAppRunning(context: Context, packageName: String): Boolean {
    val activityManager = context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    val procInfos = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
    if (procInfos != null) {
        for (processInfo in procInfos) {
            if (processInfo.processName == packageName) {
                ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(processInfo)
                if (processInfo.importance != ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
                    val app = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                    Constants.serviceCount =+ 1
                    Log.e("TEST SERVICE",Constants.serviceCount.toString())
                    startActivity(app)
                }
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Where do I have to create the file? Because if it is in the application project it does not work